# How can I do fuzzy substring matching in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, fuzzy-search

I found lots of links about fuzzy matching, comparing one string to another and seeing which gets the highest similarity score.

I have one very long string, which is a document, and a substring. The substring came from the original document, but has been converted several times, so weird artifacts might have been introduced, such as a space here, a dash there. The substring will match a section of the text in the original document 99% or more. I am not matching to see from which document this string is, I am trying to find the index in the document where the string starts.

If the string was identical because no random error was introduced, I would use `document.index(substring)`, however this fails if there is even one character difference.

I thought the difference would be accounted for by removing all characters except a-z in both the string and the substring, compare, and then use the index I generated when compressing the string to translate the index in the compressed string to the index in the real document. This worked well where the difference was whitespace and punctuation, but as soon as one letter is different it failed.

The document is typically a few pages to a hundred pages, and the substring from a few sentences to a few pages.

Comment: It seems to me that [Diff Match Patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) from Google would do to the job (the Match piece), however there is no API for Ruby. Might end up using this through Python, but would still really like to find a native solution in Ruby (getting Ruby bindings for the above would also be great).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128374/what-is-the-best-diff-library-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517998/xml-diff-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558613/diff-two-xml-doc-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925127/example-for-using-diff-ruby-gem-to-find-difference-between-two-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371474/what-is-an-algorithm-to-diff-the-two-strings-in-the-same-way-that-so-does-on-the

Comment: Related2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104075/find-similarities-between-blocks-of-text-between-many-html-documents, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916966/difflib-on-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402947/how-do-i-compare-2-html-pages-and-output-only-the-different-bits-in-ruby-or-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441458/compare-two-versions-of-a-text-file-and-find-additions-removals-with-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309356/how-to-highlighting-differences-between-2-html-files

Comment: Related3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829165/comparing-strings-of-equal-lengths-and-noting-where-the-differences-occur, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766741/comparing-ruby-hashes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818959/ruby-difference-engine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761793/how-to-do-advanced-string-comparison-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430102/how-do-i-test-xml-equality-in-ruby, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256530/how-would-i-go-about-recording-changes-in-a-large-text-field

Comment: @sawa Thank you for doing the work to include all those.

Comment: There are actually Ruby bindings to the C++ version of Google's Diff Match patch: https://github.com/elliotlaster/Ruby-Diff-Match-Patch

Answer (score 5):

You could try amatch.  It's available as a ruby gem and, although I haven't worked with fuzzy logic for a long time, it looks to have what you need.  The homepage for amatch is: https://github.com/flori/amatch.

Just bored and messing around with the idea, a completely non-optimized and untested hack of a solution follows:

```
include 'amatch'

module FuzzyFinder
  def scanner( input )
    out = [] unless block_given?
    pos = 0
    input.scan(/(\w+)(\W*)/) do |word, white|
      startpos = pos
      pos = word.length + white.length
      if block_given?
        yield startpos, word
      else
        out << [startpos, word]
      end
    end
  end

  def find( text, doc )
    index = scanner(doc)
    sstr = text.gsub(/\W/,'')
    levenshtein = Amatch::Levensthtein.new(sstr)
    minlen = sstr.length
    maxndx = index.length
    possibles = []
    minscore = minlen*2
    index.each_with_index do |x, i|
      spos = x[0]
      str = x[1]
      si = i
      while (str.length < minlen)
        i += 1
        break unless i < maxndx
        str += index[i][1]
      end
      str = str.slice(0,minlen) if (str.length > minlen)
      score = levenshtein.search(str)
      if score < minscore
        possibles = [spos]
        minscore = score
      elsif score == minscore
        possibles << spos
      end
    end
    [minscore, possibles]
  end
end
```

Obviously there are numerous improvements possible and probably necessary!  A few off the top:

1. Process the document once and store
   the results, possibly in a database.
2. Determine a usable length of string
   for an initial check, process
   against that initial substring first
   before trying to match the entire
   fragment.
3. Following up on the previous,
   precalculate starting fragments of
   that length.

Comment: It does a lot of great things, including searching for substrings, however what it doesn't do, is tell me where it found the substring!

For example, I can do this:
`irb(main):003:0>  m = Sellers.new("pattern")
=> #<Amatch::Sellers:0x0000010282d450>

irb(main):004:0> m.search ("this is a very complex pxttern which I wnat you to have")

=> 1.0`
and it will tell me that it found a match, and the Levenshtein edit distance, however what I need to know is **where** it found the match. I wonder if it is possible to get this by editing the coude of amatch.

Comment: If the substring always begins with a sentence from the original document, you could break the document into an array of sentences and compare the first n characters of the substring using amatch, recording the score (n being the sentence length in the original document).  This would give you a possible starting point.

Answer (score 3):

A simple one is [fuzzy_match](https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match)

```
require 'fuzzy_match'
FuzzyMatch.new(['seamus', 'andy', 'ben']).find('Shamus') #=> seamus
```

A more elaborated one (you wouldn't say it from this example though) is [levenshein](https://github.com/tliff/levenshtein), which computes the number of differences.

```
require 'levenshtein' 
Levenshtein.distance('test', 'test')    # => 0
Levenshtein.distance('test', 'tent')    # => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the StrikeAMatch implementation detailed here: 
[A better similarity ranking algorithm for variable length strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings)

Instead of relying on some kind of string distance (i.e. number of changes between two strings), this one looks at the character pairs patterns. The more character pairs occur in each string, the better the match. It has worked wonderfully for our application, where we search for mistyped/variable length headings in a plain text file.

There's also a gem which combines StrikeAMatch (an implementation of [Dice's coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice's_coefficient) on character-level bigrams) and Levenshtein  distance to find matches: https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the artifacts that can end up in the substring. In the simpler case where they are not part of `[a-z]` you can use parse the substring and then use `Regexp#match` on the document:

```
document = 'Ulputat non nullandigna tortor dolessi illam sectem laor acipsus.'
substr = "tortor - dolessi _%&#   +illam"

re = Regexp.new(substr.split(/[^a-z]/i).select{|e| !e.empty?}.join(".*"))
md = document.match re
puts document[md.begin(0) ... md.end(0)]
# => tortor dolessi illam
```

(Here, as we do not set any parenthesis in the Regexp, we use `begin` and `end` on the first (full match) element `0` of `MatchData`.

If you are only interested in the start position, you can use `=~` operator:

```
start_pos = document =~ re
```

Comment: That's indeed a much more elegant solution than the one I implemented in many lines of code, to be able to match correctly if the artefacts are never part of [a-z]. Thanks for this. However, as it turned out, they sometimes are, thus I need something "fuzzy" (even though, as I suggested, they will match 99%, or even 99.9%, that is not enough for Ruby's String.index).

Answer (score -2):

I have used none of them, but I found some libraries just by doing a search for 'diff' in `rubygems.org`. All of them can be installed by gem. You might want to try them. I myself is interested, so if you already know these or if you try them out, it would be helpful if you leave your comment.

- [diff](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl8950/ruby/diff.html)
- [diff-lcs](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs)
- [differ](https://github.com/pvande/differ)
- [difflcs](http://difflcs.rubyforge.org/)
- [pretty_diff](https://github.com/isabanin/pretty_diff)
- [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy)
- [kronk](https://github.com/yaksnrainbows/kronk)
- [khtmldiff](http://rubygems.org/gems/xhtmldiff)
- [gdiff](http://rubygems.org/gems/gdiff)
- [ruby_diff](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_diff)
- [tdiff](https://github.com/postmodern/tdiff)
- [diffrenderer](https://github.com/rattle/diffrenderer)
- [diffplex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/)
- [dbdiff](http://rubygems.org/gems/dbdiff)
- [diff_dirs](https://github.com/cmer/diff_dirs)
- [rsyncdiff](https://github.com/alexyoung/rsyncdiff)
- [wdiff](https://github.com/jriga/wdiff)
- [diff4all](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff4all)
- [davidtrogers-htmldiff](https://github.com/myobie/htmldiff)
- [edouard-htmldiff](https://github.com/edouard/htmldiff)
- [diff2xml](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff2xml)
- [dirdiff](http://rubygems.org/gems/dirdiff)
- [rrdiff](https://github.com/abhiyerra/rrdiff)
- [nokogiri-diff](https://github.com/postmodern/nokogiri-diff)
- [pretty-diff](https://github.com/re5et/pretty-diff)
- [easy_diff](https://github.com/Blargel/easy_diff)
- [smartdiff](http://rubygems.org/gems/smartdiff)